# Print count before and after Jinja loop

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to count the number of items in a list that have a specific value and print this count before and after I loop over the items. I tried the following:

```
{% set counter = [] %}
Counter : {{ counter|length }}

{% for i in array %}
    {% if i['maybe_true'] %}
        {% if counter.append('1') %}{% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

Counter : {{ counter|length }}
```

Rendering this produces different values before and after, as expected.

```
Counter : 0
Counter : 100
```

Is it possible to get 100 before the loop too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To your direct question: no, you can't render a variable before you calculate it.

---

Use a [`selectattr`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#selectattr) filter. It returns a generator, so use the `list` filter before using `length`.

```
{{ array|selectattr('maybe_true')|list|length }}
```

---

If your actual code is more complex than this, consider moving the logic to Python then sending the processed data to the template.

```
true_items = [i for i in array if i.maybe_true]
return render_template('index.html', array=array, true_items=true_items)
```

```
{{ true_items|length }}
{% for i in array %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
{{ true_items|length }}
```